# Were Roman Soldiers allowed to Marry? The Word παῖς in Matthew 8:5 implies that Roman Centurion had offspring

Tags: history, gospels, cultural-analysis

Matthew 8:5-13 and Luke 7:1-10 mentions a story of Centurion whose servant was healed by Jesus. Matthew in 8:5 uses the word pais which may mean son. However, Luke 7:2 uses the word dulos specifying that the one healed was a slave. One of the interpretation to resolve the difference of words between Matthew and Luke is that Roman soldiers were not allowed to marry. In light of this the word pais of Matthew must be translated as servant and not son. This interpretation also goes well in line with the word used by Luke.

Requesting for clarification concerning the following:
Were Romans soldiers were allowed to Marry in light of the passage Matthew 8:5-13 and Luke 7:1-10?

Comment: This is a good question but not very suitable for BH. Perhaps you would find better answers on History SE. I have voted to close.

Comment: See this: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26266/did-the-centurion-cornelius-of-acts-10-have-an-illicit-family

Comment: Cassius Dio 60:24 does mentions that Roman soldiers were legally not permitted to maryy. Thanks to fdb for pointing to the discussion thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Cassius Dio 60:24 the men serving in army were not legally allowed to marry.

> The men serving in the army, since they could not legally have wives, were granted the privileges of married men.

Cassius Dio was a Roman statement and historian. He wrote 80 books and covered Roman history until 229 A.D.

Acknowledgement:
1. Quotation can be accessed [here](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Cassius_Dio/60*.html)
2. Thanks to fdb for mentioning the discussion at stackexchange at [link](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26266/did-the-centurion-cornelius-of-acts-10-have-an-illicit-family)